# PHP password_verify()

Tags: php, hash

I didn't take asking this question lightly as I've seriously gone over 50 links throughout the entire night trying to get password_verify() to work.

1- The Hash Is 100% Correct.
2- The Plain Text Verison Is 100% Correct.
3- The Hash Length Is In Fact 60.
4- Tried Password_Default And Password_Bcrypt
5- It Does Successfully Pull The Password Out Of The Database.

BUT

```
if(password_verify($answer,$secAnswer)){ } IS ALWAYS false.
```

Here is my Code.

```
  function anti_injection_login($sql, $formUse = true){
$sql = preg_replace("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|,|'|#|\*|--|\\\\)/i","",$sql);
$sql = trim($sql);
$sql = strip_tags($sql);
if(!$formUse || !get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  $sql = addslashes($sql);
return $sql;
}


  $email = anti_injection_login($_POST['email']);
  $answer = anti_injection_login($_POST['answer']);
  $queryAccount = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Accounts where email= '$email'");
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($queryAccount);
  if($count == 1){
     $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($queryAccount);
     $secAnswer = $rows['secretkey'];

     if(password_verify($answer,$secAnswer)){
         echo "Successful";
     }else{
         echo "Try Again";
     }
  }
```

the anti_injection_login is just to stop people from injecting it.
This is NOT the problem. 
As no matter where I put an Echo with the 
$secAnswer and $answer it is always correct exactly as I would expect it to be.

Is there something I am missing guys?
I am seriously stumped on this now.

(Yes this is the entire script). So I'm not leaving anything out.
But as mentioned, it is successfully pulling the hash, (and is correct) according to the database version it's identical.

And the word I used for the hash is Identical (Tried both Upper case and Lowercase).

Comment: Please use prepared statements. You don't need to roll your own sanitation.

Comment: What does `$rows['secretkey']` contains (provide example). And show how you generate `secretkey` hash. Also your `anti_injection_login` will ruin my logins if password is something like `aliform_at_insert`

Comment: Sorry, `anti_injection_login()` is asking for your site to be hacked. Prepared statements is what you *need*.

Comment: You should not modify the password that gets sent in, any change to (or forgetting to use...) your `anti_injection_login()` function can break valid passwords. Just use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: Alright so it's seeming I just need to get rid of that function all together and use prepared statements? Sorry new to PHP..

Comment: *"the anti_injection_login is [..] NOT the problem"* – It may very well be, depending on what your password is. It's *modifying* the value, so may lead to it not matching the original hash.

Comment: In general it's pretty simple to prove whether `password_*` works or not: `password_hash` a plaintext, and immediately `password_verify` the hash against the plaintext. That must always work. From there, debug your values in detail. Output the hash and plaintext at every step and figure *when* it gets altered. Not *if*, but *when*, because surely somewhere along the line something gets altered so it won't match anymore.

Comment: And please read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) gives a very clear example:

```
<?php
// See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

First of all, your password hash needs to be created by the `password_hash()` function when the user registers.

At login, you then pass the password from the form into `password_verify()` along with the stored hash from the database.

However, your code passes the form data through `anti_injection_login()` which is doing who-knows-what with any given input. You shouldn't need to sanitize the password if you're passing it straight into `password_verify()`. I highly recommend you use prepared statements to retrieve the hash from the database, and pass `$_POST['answer']` straight into `password_verify()`.